# update custom field user profile from front end form

Tags: users, profiles

I've created a custom field called "istituto" in the user profile section that works properly if it is updated within the profile itself.

I have created a custom registration form with a field called "istituto".
The submit button of this form is a div with class "*.form_acc_2*" and the field "instituto" has an id *#dhvc_form_control_istituto*.
I wrote in `jquery` a code that fetches the value when inserted:

```
var istituto = '';
jQuery('div.form_acc_2').click(function(){   
   var istituto = jQuery('input#dhvc_form_control_istituto').val();
   if(istituto.length != 0)
   alert(istituto);
   return istituto;   
   })
```

Now the value is in the variable "instituto". How can I update the custom field "istituto" inside the user profile using the `update_user_meta` function?

Did I use a wrong approach?

Comment: I don't understand which value do you want to save in the user meta ?

Comment: the value inside input "istituto" ... here:

<input data-field-name="istituto" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="dhvc_form_control_istituto" name="istituto" value="" class="dhvc-form-control dhvc-form-control-istituto dhvc-form-value " placeholder="">

Answer (score 0):

ok everything fixed at the time, I modified the oroginal form with "register_form" and then I called the input with that value in my custom form.